# How can I linearize annual sales forecasts into a sequential number of series, while maintaining contraints on area under the curve

Tags: integration

Run into a problem at work with forecasting and thought people here might be able to help.

Our sales team have provided me product forecasts in the form of annual volumes (eg. FY14=100M units, FY15=80M units etc).

The problem is that, when plotting these over time, we end up with a number of step changes, and little insight into anticipating approximate volumes in any given month.

I've been asked to linearize the points, to reflect smoother transitions from one volume scenario to another (based on the assumption that any consumption 
changes will happen over time rather than instantaneously).

Below is a shiny paint image of how I am currently conceptualising my problem.

[image: conceptualisation of sales forecasting]

My dilemma is how to identify the individual starting/ending points of each year (and, in practicality, the intermediate monthly values) such that 
a) the total area under the lines equals the full year sales forecast (eg. the area under the line from P1 to P2 = 100, from P2 to P3 = 70)
b) there are no major 'disconnects' between one year and the next, ie. if dec 2014 was 5M units, jan 2015 should be roughly the same 
   (+- some amount to adjust for the trend occuring in the new sales year)

From my initial playing around, I saw that attempting to blindly fix one point (eg, P1) has a run-on impact on the remainder of the series, 
such that sales in some months may go negative in order to continue meeting the constraint that the area = annual sales volume.

Is there a way to solve for P1, P2, P3, P4 etc such that the above constraints (especially a) are held? Would  need to be extendable, as ultimately would be mapped for several more years into the future.

Many, many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, the middle point of each year is fixed by the forecast, but the slope over the year is not.  The figure below shows this-whichever top line you put on the box, you get the same area.  The horizontal spacing should remain uniform as it reflects the same time span for each interval.  You have four free parameters and three constraints-matching the values at the three junctions between the years.  That leaves you a one dimensional continuum of solutions.  As you say, you can pick P1 arbitrarily, then all the other points are determined-you find P2 by extending the line from P1 through the midpoint of FY14, then draw the line through P2 and the midpoint of FY15 to find P3 and so on.  Your total area is proportional to $P1+2P2+2P3+2P4+P5$ (see the extended trapezoid rule in numerical integration) so this sum is fixed.  Probably the most attractive rendering (which may have nothing to do with reality) is to minimize the bends.  You can make a spreadsheet with the even rows being the midpoints of the years, then enter a value for P1, calculate P2 as twice the midpoint minus P1 and so on.  Adjust P1 by eye.  I show three versions below.  The middle is clearly the most elegant for this dataset, but I don't have a prescription for how to find it.[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is a way to do this. You do have a lot of freedom though.

I am not sure why you're asked specifically to "linearize". It seems to me that there are many smoother curves that might be more useful.

Anyway, here's the model of the problem I propose. Suppose we generalize to a piecewise polynomial function of degree $d$ instead of a piecewise linear function. The pieces are split by points $x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n$, so there are $n$ pieces. The target function is split into $n$ pieces, each of which is defined by
$$
f_i(x) = \sum_{j=0}^d a_{i,j}x^j
$$
on $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$. We want to find all $a_{i,j}$. There are $(d + 1) \times n$ of them.

We are given areas of the pieces as $A_1, \ldots, A_n$. This gives us $n$ equations, namely
$$
A_i = \int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} f_i(x) dx = \sum_{j=0}^d \frac{1}{j+1}\left(x_i^{j+1} - x_{i-1}^{j+1}\right)a_{i,j}.
$$
We are left with $d \times n$ degrees of freedom.
The next requirement is that the function has to be continuous. This translates to $f_i(x_i) = f_{i+1}(x_i)$ for $i = 1, 2, \ldots, n - 1$, giving $n - 1$ equations:
$$
\sum_{j=0}^d x_i^j(a_{i+1,j} - a_{i,j}) = 0 \qquad ; i = 1, 2, \ldots, n - 1.
$$

Now you still have $(d - 1) \times n - 1$ degrees of freedom. You should try to come up with conditions that make sense to you to pin down a unique solution.

**Suggestion**

The matching value condition can be generalized to matching derivatives of all orders less than $d$. This makes a total of $(n - 1) \times d$ equations (including matching values). Combining with the condition on the area, we get $(n - 1) \times d + n$ equations. We are still left with $(d + 1) \times n - (n - 1) \times d - n = d$ degrees of freedom.

Now it's all up to you. For example, you can specify the values of all derivatives of order less than $d$ at $x_0$ of $f_1$. This will give you exactly $d$ equations. Another common stipulation is that some higher order derivatives at $x_0$ and $x_n$ are zero. (For example, if you choose $d = 4$, you may set $f_1'''(x_0) = f_1^{(iv)}(x_0) = f_n'''(x_n) = f_n^{(iv)}(x_n) = 0$.)

[I haven't actually tried this so I don't really know how well it would work.]

**Linear Case**

When $d = 1$, you can impose one more condition. For example, you can choose $f_1(x_0) = \alpha$ for an arbitrary $\alpha$. Ross Millikan showed you in a picture that different solutions can obtained from different $\alpha$. If I have to choose one special $\alpha$, I may pick $\alpha$ that minimizes variation in some way.

One example is to use total variation defined by $\sum_{i=1}^n |f_i(x_i) - f_i(x_{i-1})| = \sum_{i=1}^n |a_{i,1}(x_i - x_{i-1})|$. Solving for a choice of $a_{i,j}$ that works and minimizes this function can be done by one call to the simplex method.